# Kendo UI kendo is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui

I'm just starting to use Kendo UI and I'm having trouble getting one of the demos to work. I get  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'observable' of undefined on line 43. How can I fix this? Any help is appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="./styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="./js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/kendo.core.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="example">
    <div class="demo-section k-header">
        <div class="box-col" style="width: 300px">
            <h4>Change the value</h4>
            <input data-role="slider"
                   data-min="0"
                   data-max="50"
                   data-small-step="5"
                   data-large-step="10"
                   data-bind="visible: isVisible,
                              enabled: isEnabled,
                              value: selectedNumber,
                              events: { change: onChange }"
                   style="width: 180px">
        </div>
        <div class="box-col console-section">
            <h4>Console</h4>
            <div class="console"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-col" style="width: 300px">
            <h4>Configuration</h4>
            <div>
                <label><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isEnabled">Enable</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isVisible">Visible</label>
            </div>
        </div>       
    </div>
<script>
    var viewModel = kendo.observable({
        selectedNumber: 0,
        isEnabled: true,
        isVisible: true,
        onChange: function() {
            kendoConsole.log("event :: change (" + this.get("selectedNumber") + ")");
        }
    });
    kendo.bind($("#example"), viewModel);
</script>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must have a script that is not loading.  My guess is that your pathing is wrong. Be aware that when your `href` and `src` start with `./` that means look for a subdirectory of the current directory.  There is a good chance you don't want the dot there.

I was able to recreate your example successfully here: http://jsfiddle.net/95w1e3s3/

Answer (score 0):

You need to include kendo.all.min.js instead of kendo.core.min.js. It appears that .observable is not defined, so perhaps you need another script to bring in that part of the kendo framework or MVVM binding is not supported on the free version.

Answer (score 0):

kendo.core.min.js has not observable property. 
You have to add kendo.binder.min.js, kendo.data.min.js or kendo.all.min.js.

Answer (score 0):

You can try fo this:
check your **"jquery.min.js" version compatibility** with kendo version. this might be the issue in you case.

most of the time you can **use jquery 1.8 version with kendo 2015.x.x version**